# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' thrown when working with event.target.id

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am attempting to perform a HostListener on my component, specifying that I want something to happen when anything **BUT** a specific element is clicked; however, I am receiving the error:

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

The code runs fine in the UI, but I can't shake this error thrown by linting.

I understand that I must use a type for the this, such as  if I were performing it about an input element. However I am performing the check on a normal `<div>` that is being clicked...

I am unsure of how to proceed.

```
@HostListener('document:click', [$event'])
myClick(event: MouseClick): void {
  if (event.target.id !== 'some-id') {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

I have been playing around with something such as:

`if (<HTMLElement>event.target.id...`

but I cannot find a fix for this...

Comment: Do a console.log of event and check if there is any `target` object

Comment: Use `(event.target as HTMLElement).id` or `(<HTMLElement>event.target).id`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will post @ConnorsFan's answer since his comment worked out for me.

In the end I went with using `(<HTMLElement>event.target).id`.

It seems that my attempt at setting event.target.id was misguided as I understand now that the  type should be applied to the target, and the ID is just an attribute of said target element.

Comment: You mean using `(event.target as HTMLElement).id` right?

Comment: @abumalick It looks like I'd not formatted the answer correctly. You can now see that I've essentially done the same as you, just maybe not as elegantly.